# Magento shopping cart pricing rules not applying correctly

Tags: php, model-view-controller, magento

I have been having a problem with shopping cart price rules that aren't being applied correctly in the cart.  The problem occurs when there are multiple discounts.  Here is a specific example:

Discount A:

- Product: 3 Book Set
- Price: $20 each book
- Discount: $10 (when you buy all 3)

Discount B:

- Product: Suit (jacket and pants)
- Price: $500 each piece
- Discount: $50 (when you buy both)

Here is the situation:
When the suit is listed first and the books second, all discounts are taken ($50 + $10 = $60).  However, when the books are first, only the suit discount is taken ($50).

Using firebug/firephp I have been able to see that for the first case, the discount is less than the price of the first product and all the discounts can be taken off that product.

In the second case, the discount is more than the price of the first product.  When this happens, the $50 discount is spread across the 3 books.  It takes $20 off the first book, $20 off the second, $10 off the third; but then the $10 discount for the books is not processed.

I need to know where to look next.  What models/methods are involved in processing shopping cart price rules?  How do I go about tracing the code so I can find out where the error happens?

Comment: Have you set up "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions" this values in both rules? Seems price rule applies discount to all the products, but should only to matched elements.

Comment: Both rules apply "Fixed amount discount for whole cart".  I did try the "Apply the rule..." for the book set, but not the suit.  It didn't seem to make a difference, but maybe I should try the suit.

Comment: That seemed to be it.  Setting "Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions" appeared to clear up the issue.  It seems odd that "Fixed amount discount for whole cart" has to apply the discount product-by-product.